# Problems with iOS Facebook authorization

Tags: ios, post, photo, facebook-wall

I'm using the latest Facebook iOS beta SDK and trying to post a photo to my wall. I'm using the following code:

https://gist.github.com/3145581

My app calls "sessionOpenWithPermissions", loads the facebook app, I can accept the app and its permissions fine, but then nothing happens. From then on, all it does is load the facebook app, display a "Loading..." message in a dialog, then the dialog quits and I'm left in the facebook app. It doesn't even reach the block inside sessionOpenWithPermissions...

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I actually just reverted to the stable Facebook SDK, and the same thing occurs with:

> [delegate.facebook authorize:[NSArray
>   arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access", nil]];

So in fact something is going wrong with authorization. I've double checked the app ID, the settings on Facebook, the URL scheme... It's hard to explain though because there are no errors.

Comment: is your Facebook app well set on the app dashboard (iOS bundle id)? Do you handle the open url?

Comment: Yes and yes. Bundle ID is correct, iOS SSO is enabled, I call handleOpenURL (which btw is never called because it remains inside the facebook app). And my app store ID is not functional because it's in development. No idea what's up.

Comment: what about the url scheme in the info.plist?

Comment: ^^^ Was just about to say that it was fixed by adding the URL scheme/identifier to the plist. I knew I was missing something! Feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: That was only a probable solution... there's no need to post an answer. The important thing is that you solved your problem ;)